# Why is my function returning number like (-33686016), but doesn't return needed value?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I need to make dynamic array assignment for class, where I show how they work and how to pass them to a function. It seems that the code is running without errors, but it returns value of `-33686016`, but I need it to return sum of ints that I pass in.

So I wanted to make a calculator which works with dynamic array, so you can input as many ints as you need to sum on loop, haven't done the loop part yet tho, but it doesn't even work without it. I've tried to add pointers and got to a point where it returns memory address. But still can't get the value.

Source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "saskait_funkc.h"

int main()
{

    int size;
    std::cin >> size;
    int *arr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i <= (size - 1); i++) {
        std::cin >> arr[i]; }

    int kopa =  sask(arr, size);
    std::cout << kopa;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Function:

```
int sask(int *num, int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        sum = sum + num[i];}

    return sum;
}
```

So for example first input (2 which means how many ints you will input next), then ( 1 and 2 which are ints that you want to sum) and output should be 3, but it outputs `-33686016`.

Without arrays it works, but I need to include dynamic array

Comment: `i <= size`-> `i < size` - you are accessing `num` out of bounds

Comment: You have _undefined behavior_ in your loop regarding accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: Unless it's a requirement for the assignment/exercise then don't use pointers and dynamic allocation. Use `std::vector` instead. Still prone to the problem you have with out of bounds indexing, but better in so many other ways.

Comment: OHH thanks for the tip, didn't even see that mistake.

Comment: This is correct but odd, `for (int i = 0; i <= (size - 1); i++) {`. The normal version is `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {` You'll get used to counting from zero soon enough.

Comment: @ReinisZīverts Did you tried to change your function `sack` as my post?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment - array length enable you to access last element as `arr[length-1]`.

Therefor, in your `sask` function you cannot access `num[i]` when `i=size` which is allow by your `for-loop` condition - if you do access it it can change the `sum` var in unexpected ways (as change it to "-33686016").

The way to do it is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // without the "=" sign
```